# Regex vs String.Contains

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hola. I'm failing to write a method to test for words within a plain text or html document. I was reasonably literate with regex, and I am newer to c# (from way more java).

Just 'cause,

```
string html = source.ToLower();
string plaintext = Regex.Replace(html, @"<(.|\n)*?>", " "); // remove tags
plaintext = Regex.Replace(plaintext, @"\s+", " "); // remove excess white space
```

and then,

```
string tag = "c++";
bool foundAsRegex = Regex.IsMatch(plaintext,@"\b" + Regex.Escape(tag) + @"\b");
bool foundAsContains = plaintext.Contains(tag);
```

For a case where "c++" should be found, sometimes foundAsRegex is true and sometimes false. My google-fu is weak, so I didn't get much back on "what the hell". Any ideas or pointers welcome!

edit:

I'm searching for matches on skills in resumes. for example, the distinct value "c++".

edit:

a real excerpt is given below:

"...administration- c, c++, perl, shell programming..."

Comment: @CanSpice, I was trying to edit for formatting, too...you beat me to it. I added the .net tag, too.

Comment: maybe take a look at the Html agility pack for parsing html docs - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: you kids are snappy here, thanks. sometimes the users give me bad html and sometimes plain text, so the html tags are secondary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.  Given the expression `\bc\+\+\b`, you have a problem.  "+" is a non-word character.  So searching for the pattern in "xxx c++, xxx", you're not going to find anything.  There's no "word break" after the "+" character.

If you're looking for non-word characters then you'll have to change your logic.  Not sure what the best thing would be.  I suppose you can use `\W`, but then it's not going to match at the beginning or end of the line, so you'll need `(^|\W)` and `(\W|$)` ... which is ugly.  And slow, although perhaps still fast enough depending on your needs.

Comment: ah! i figured that was what was going on with the similar reaction against "c#"; however, i think i also have inconsitent matches against only alphanumeric words. i'm checking that now. if that's not the case, i will surely close this question.

Comment: ok. that's it. it was bad regex, and nothing more. well, there's bad user text, but regex can't do anything about bad users. thanks for the help and perspective!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is turning into:

```
/\bc\+\+\b/
```

Which means you're looking for a word boundary, followed by the string `c++`, followed by another word boundary. This means it won't match on strings like `abc++`, whereas `plaintext.Contains` will succeed.

If you can give us examples of where your regex fails when you expected it to succeed, then we can give you a more definite answer.

**Edit:** My original regex was `/\bc++\b/`, which is incorrect, as `c++` is being passed to `Regex.Escape()`, which escapes out regular expression metacharacters like `+`. I've fixed it above.

Comment: Wouldn't the `Regex.Escape` turn it into `\bc\+\+\b`?

Comment: @Daniel: You left that comment as I was editing my answer. :-)

Comment: @canspice. that's exactly what i'm looking for, but it doesn't work how i expect. if "c++" is mid-stream - eg, "java, bad grammar, bad punctation,,, c++, some other hoo-ha" - it may find it, it may not. that is what my breakpoints show me, yes, they do.

Comment: @underachiever: Please give us exact examples of strings that match and don't match.

Comment: @canspice, i edited the main text just now. that "c++" matches on String.Contains but not Regex with the proper escapes. it also behaves inconsistently against "c#" and more ordinary text like "perl".

Comment: @underachiever: Okay, that's weird. I can't see why that string wouldn't match. Unfortunately I'm on a Linux box and can't whip up a quick program to try different things out.

Comment: @canspice, yeah, i think so, too. i wondered if it was some mystery character in the files, but wouldn't the white space strip-out take care of that? i've used regex lots in java, so i thought maybe i missed something obvious in c#. i'm gonna run through different files to see if i can find a predictable anomaly, but this is such a simple problem, right?